# Difference between class scope and object scope design patterns

Tags: design-patterns

Apparently design patterns have a ton of classifications. One I am struggling with is whether or not the pattern is a class scoped pattern or an object scoped pattern. Of course no documentation exists on the differences between the two, so I'm asking your opinion.

The GoF book defines it as:

"Class patterns deal with relationships between classes and their subclasses. These relationships are established through inheritance, so they are static-fixed at compile-time. Object patterns deal with object relationships, which can be changed at run-time and are more dynamic. Almost all patterns use inheritance to some extent. So the only patterns labelled "class patterns" are those that focus on class relationships. Note that most patterns are in the object scope."

Problem is, there are only class relationships as an object is nothing without its class. I've never heard of "object relationships" outside of this book.

Comment: The logical flow of your code isn't defined by inheritance, so it's in the object scope, as I understand it.

Comment: Yes, please migrate this to Programmers.SE. It is more appropriate there and I cannot find a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

This boils down to composition vs. inheritance.

Let's take a look at one pattern that you can do in both ways.

The `adapter pattern` is, as the name implies, an adapter between two classes that are otherwise incompatible.

Say you write a 3D engine and you need a `Point` class. You have your `Point` all ready and it kind of works, but then you find another class `OtherPoint` in some library that does everything your class should be doing in a nicer way, but its methods have different names. Your 3D engine expects your `Point` class.

**What can you do to make both classes compatible in order to use `OtherPoint` class?**

1. `Point extends OtherPoint` inheritance for the win. `Point` receives all the functionality it needs. The methods specific to your engine that `Point` declares simply call the corresponding ones from `OtherPoint`. This is the **class pattern** style of the adapter.
2. On the other hand, you could do `Point(OtherPoint constructorParameter)` to receive an `OtherPoint` object. The idea is similar: the `Point` methods now don't delegate to the methods it received via inheritance but to the object it received as a parameter in the constructor. This is the **object pattern** style of the adapter. This is a comparable to the wrapper pattern.

**How does that explain the GoF statement(s)?**

> "Class patterns [...] are static-fixed at compile-time.

By saying `Point extends OtherPoint` you say that a `Point` **is a** `OtherPoint`. It's a plain old simple inheritance chain. You cannot change them at run time.

> Object patterns [...] which can be changed at run-time and are more dynamic

By saying `Point(OtherPoint constructorParameter)` you say that a `Point` **has a** `OtherPoint`. Maybe you find out that this library has an even fancier class, i.e. `FancierOtherPoint extends OtherPoint`. You can pass that to `Point` as well. In fact you can pass any sublcass of `OtherPoint` to `Point`, because of polymorphism.

Maybe `FancierOtherPoint` only works on certain hardware and you have to check for that hardware at run time. With the **object pattern** style of the adapter, you can do exactly that: decide **dynamically** what class to use.

---

> I've never heard of "object relationships" outside of this book.

"object relationships" is not  special phrase. It means exactly what is says: relationships between objects. Design patterns are just names for common ways to define relationships between objects.

If I were to say  "3.14159265359..." you'd probably stop me to ask if I mean "pi". Now if you were to tell me you "inherit from that one class to make things compatible and delegate methods and..." I would stop you to ask if you mean the adapter pattern.

It simplifies communication and everybody has a rough understanding of what the conversation is about without explaining everything in full detail.

Answer (score 1):

A class is a blueprint or template or set of instructions to build a specific type of object. A object is a instance of a class.

So a class patterns plays with things you can do with classes like abstraction, inheritance, interfaces, visibility scope, etc. A Object pattern plays with things you can do whith instance like references, pointers, creation and destruction, etc.

Anyway, I don't see this concept very important because most of the patterns mixes classes and objecs techniques to acomplish the objective.